# Number of rearrangements of letters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

We have the letters 'WINPRESENT'. I want to calculate the rearrangements of these letters that contain either the word 'WIN' or the word 'PRESENT' or both of them.

I have done the following:

The subword 'WIN' is contained in $8!$ rearrangements. The subword 'PRESENT' is contained in $4!$ rearrangements. We have calculated twice 'WINPRESENT' and twice 'PRESENTWIN'.

So the total amount of rearrangements that contain either the word 'WIN' or the word 'PRESENT' or both of them is equal to $8!+4!-2$, or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good approach, but not quite right: when considering the number of arrangements which contain WIN, you need to take account of the fact that there are two Es in the remaining letters. As it is, you've counted $\text{SPE}_1(\text{WIN})\text{NE}_2\text{TR}$ and $\text{SPE}_2(\text{WIN})\text{NE}_1\text{TR}$ as different arrangements.

Comment: Ah ok! But how can we calculate then the number of rearrangements?

Comment: Is it maybe $7!+4!-2$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar no, you have only counted the arrangements with WIN twice each, so you need $8!/2$ rather than $7!$.

Comment: We also have two N's at 'WINPRESENT'. Does this also change the number of rearrangements?

Comment: @MaryStar No, we've only counted two arrangements with both words (WINPRESENT and PRESENTWIN), and this is the right number (swapping the Ns doesn't give a different arrangement). And if we only have one word, the remaining letters have exactly one N, so there is no problem.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)